# Is there any format specifier in Python format() function to get decimal part without the dot?

Tags: python, format, format-specifiers

Is there any format specifier in Python `format()` function which can be used in order to get a specified number of digits from the decimal part without the dot?

For example I would like to get only `86` from the float `0.86`.

EDIT:
The workaround I do right now is this:

```
"{:.0f}".format(num*100)
```

The answers so far suggest workarounds like this one or using string manipulations. I am aware of these solutions. What I am asking for, is if there is a way to do this only with a format specifier.

Comment: Just multiply it by 100?

Comment: `"{0:g}".format(num).split(".",1)[-1]`  is one way .... I guess

Comment: @AndrewLi, this is the workaround I am following now to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any specific stuff in str.format that we could use to accomplish this, but this is how I would go about it.

You can cast the float to an integer which will chop off the decimal to the right of the float.  Then just subtract them and you should get just the decimal part.

```
my_float = 12.12121200

print("Just the decimal: {0}".format(
    int(str(my_float - int(my_float)).split(".")[1])
))
```

Comment: This prints `0.12121199999999988`, that is with a dot. I would like the result to exclude the `0.` prefix. The result as I prefer it would be: `12121199999999988`.

Answer (score 0):

You could `.replace`?

such as

```
decimal = .85
int(str(decimal).replace('.', ''))
```

This is not a .format thought, Hope it helps anyways.